# Json.parse return null when output is 0

Tags: powershell

I am facing issue in json.parse for output '0' in my orchestration activity.

This is the script:

```
var output = executionResult.output;
var outputJSON = null;
if (output.indexOf('{ "') > -1) {
try {
var jsonValue = output.substring(output.indexOf('{ "'));
outputJSON = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
}
activityOutput.totalUsers = outputJSON.TotalUsers;
}
```

In powershell output , I am getting TotalUsers= 0;

But after parsing in my workflow, i am getting totalUsers =  null

This is only happening if count is 0, else i am getting correct count

Any help?

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing the input JSON file correctly in your workflow?

Comment: Yes. because if i get TotalUsers =1, thenit is coming correctly totalUsers = 1

Comment: I assume the item TotalUsers isn't always set in the JSON. The code snippet looks like C#, then you could use outputJSON.TotalUsers ?? 0.

Comment: Please adjust the tags by [edit]ing your question, I see no relevance to PowerShell. You should also take the [tour] and read [ask]